# Запрос из Java-кода на сервер с помощью REST

Tags: java, http, rest

Необходимо передавать из java-программы строку на сервер, там её вставить в определённое поле, инициировать submit и строку из другого поля возвращать в код. Например URL: https://ipinfodb.com, в поле ip-address lookup нужно вставить строку (ip-адрес) и вернуть то, что будет в поле Coordinates of city. Возможно ли это сделать с помощью  REST, и как?

Answer (score 1):

- открываем сайт.
- открывайте DevTools, переходите на вкладку Network
- нажимаете насайте на кнопку `Lookup`

  в Network отображаются запросы, который выполняет сайт, можно увидеть, что выполняется POST запрос на  https://ipinfodb.com/ с телом `{"ip": "194.186.88.2"}`

Вам нужно выполнить такой запрос и получить ответ в виде HTML.  Дальше парсить этот HTML и вытянуть нужные вам данные.

Comment: Спасибо. Но оказалось что у сервиса просто открытый API, чего достаточно.